# Реализация drag&drop на IOS

Tags: ipad, drag-n-drop, ios, iphone, javascript

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно реализовать
`drag and drop` на iOS. На компьютере все работает. А вот на iphone/ipad...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Парочка библиотек:

- [Mobile Drag And Drop Summary](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/cmsfiles/assets/File/mobiledragdrop.html);
- [jquery-ui-for-ipad-and-iphone](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-for-ipad-and-iphone/).

Comment: Спасибо,попробуемс

Comment: Вторая хорошая)

Answer (score 2):

```
//создаем жест и цепляем обработчик для него в лице gestureAction:

UIPanGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gestureAction:)] autorelease];

 gesture.delegate = self;
[someView addGestureRecognizer:gesture];

//описываем поведение для разных состояний жеста

- (void)gestureAction:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
        switch (gesture.state)
        {
            case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
            {
                [self dragWillBeginWithGesture:gesture];
                self.currentGesture = gesture;
                break;
            }

            case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
            {
                [self dragDidMoveWithGesture:gesture];
                break;
            }

            case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
            {
                [self dragDidEndWithGesture:gesture];
                break;
            }

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

после этого, естественно, описываем поведение каждой функции, а именно

- `dragWillBeginWithGesture:`
- `dragDidMoveWithGesture:`
- `dragDidEndWithGesture:`

Comment: И Вам спасибо)